# bootstrap 4 list group with tab panel: show content only if active

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, django-views

I have a list group with tab panel set up using bootstrap 4.
For each item in the list, i show some data in the righthand tab. but, it's a long list.
I'd rather only show the data for the active item. So, rather than calculating all the data and when the page loads (including graphs), I'd rather it only happen when an item is clicked (and it becomes the active item).

I don't know much anything about javascript.
but, searching around here, I see that I can get the items for a particular class: `var items = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item active");`

but, I have no idea how to use this in html to limit when I show the data.
here is the basic code for my list group. The list contains titles and thumbnails for posts, with some other info like when it was posted and the keywords (coded using django in python)

```
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group mostly-customized-scrollbar" id="list-tab" role="tablist" style="border-radius:6px;">
        {% for post in posts %}
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start"
               id="list-{{post.pk}}-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-{{ post.pk }}"
               role="tab" aria-controls="post-{{ post.pk }}">
                <!--FILTER RESULTS-->
                <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <span style="margin-right:15px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; float:left;">{{ post.thumbnail_tag }}</span>
                    <span class="notranslate mb-2"  style="display:block;">{{ post.title }}</span>
                </div>
<!--                <small class="text-muted mb-5">{{post.posted_on}}</small>-->
<!--                <small class="text-muted">{{post.klist}}</small>-->
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

then, here is the tabbed area.

```
<div class="col-8">
   <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
       {% for post in posts %}
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-{{post.pk}}"
               role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-{{post.pk}}-list">
               <div class="card text-retro-brown">
                   <div class="card-header card-header-retro-tan" >
                   ADD STUFF HERE
                   </div>
                   <div class="card-body card-retro-tan">
                       <h5 class="card-title bg-retro-lightblue"></h5>
                       ADD STUFF HERE LIKE GRAPHS RELATED TO THE CLICKED ITEM
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        {% endfor %}
   </div>
</div>
```

What I would like is something like:

```
{% for post in posts if post is active item in group list% }
```

so that data and whatnot are only retrieved, converted to html graph, and displayed when an item is clicked.